# mySQL: import huge database from command line (windows) / constraints

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin

i'm requiring some advice for importing data to my local xampp:

i need to import app. 15 tables of 60 total from the server database (the whole database is way too big and i only require a few) - so far i performed the following tasks:

I exported each table separately with phpMyAdmin and checked the "Disable foreign key checks" in order to avoid problems with constraints - then imported each table like this:

`mysql -u root db12345 -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET autocommit=0 ; source mytable.sql ; COMMIT ; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;"`

Performing these task for 15 tables is rather time consuming so i was wondering if there's a better way like:

Export all required tables from the server console into one file and generally turn off the foreign key checks for avoiding errors about constraints? It also seems like if a specific order of the tables being imported is still causing constraints error although `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is set to 0.

The import process also takes way too long - my PC is pretty fast but it still takes about ~20 minutes for importing a 300 MB sized table - is it possible to speed up the import process?

Comment: I think that (create tables w/o indices and FKs - import data - alter tables and add indices/FKs) will be faster.

Comment: @Akina, I have tried this extensively. It doesn't save as much time as you might think. The import is faster, especially if you have many indexes. But then you have to do the second step of adding the indexes, which does take time. It's practically a wash.

Comment: @BillKarwin In my practice separate indices/FKs creation saves ~10-15% of time. Increasing the amount of indices and the database size increases the difference.

Comment: Please explain why you can't simply reference the main database, using only the tables you need to touch.  Is the server on the other side of the world?  Is it too busy for your extra load?  Will you be modifying the schema?  Other?  I ask this to look for a different approach to the _real_ problem.  The 20 minutes may not be fixable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking you computer to function as a decent server. Could you do whatever you want to develop or test with less data?
If there are several years of date how much do your really need to test what you want to test?
If it was an ERP I would suggest taking the last months documents but all of the articles, customers and suppliers.